# Completed Town Generator

Tags: java, random

I am a beginner, and I believe I made a simple and efficient program to do it in. I can add more methods for more detail for future updates, but it's a workable bit.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TownGenerator
{
private static Scanner k;
public static void main (String [] args)
{

    System.out.println("Ayyy, here's a town for you. Want a City, Town, or Village?");
    System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
    k = new Scanner(System.in);
    String TownType = k.nextLine();
    if (TownType.equalsIgnoreCase("City"))
    {
        System.out.println("You chose a City, here it is!");
        String name1 = city();
        String name2 = city2();
        System.out.println("Then name of the city is: "+name1+name2+"!");
        System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
        String name3 = percent();
        String name4 = demo();
        String name5 = demo2();
        System.out.println("The populas is comprised "+name3+" "+name4+" and the next leading majority being "+name5);
        System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
        String name6 = status();
        System.out.println("This Cities general behaviour is"+name6);
        System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
        String name7 = geo();
        String name8 = geo2();
        System.out.println("The Cities geography is"+name7+name8);
        System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");

    }
    if (TownType.equalsIgnoreCase("Town"))
    {
        System.out.println("You chose a Town, here it is!");
        String name1 = town();
        String name2 = town2();
        System.out.println("Then name of the town is: "+name1+name2+"!");
        System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
        System.out.println("Here's the demographic!");
        String name3 = percent();
        String name4 = demo();
        String name5 = demo2();
        System.out.println("The populas is comprised "+name3+" "+name4+" and the next leading majority being "+name5);
        System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
        String name6 = status();
        System.out.println("This Town's general behaviour is"+name6);
        System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
        String name7 = geo();
        String name8 = geo2();
        System.out.println("The Town's geography is"+name7+name8);
        System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");

    }
    if (TownType.equalsIgnoreCase("Village"))
    {
        System.out.println("You chose a Village, here it is!");
        String name1 = village();
        String name2 = village2();
        System.out.println("Then name of the village is: "+name1+name2+"!");
        System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
        String name3 = percent();
        String name4 = demo();
        String name5 = demo2();
        System.out.println("The populas is comprised "+name3+" "+name4+" and the next leading demographic being "+name5);
        System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
        String name6 = status();
        System.out.println("This Village's general behaviour is"+name6);
        System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
        String name7 = geo();
        String name8 = geo2();
        System.out.println("The Village's geography is"+name7+name8);
        System.out.println("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
    }
}
public static String city()
{
        Random r = new Random();
        int a = 1+r.nextInt(10);
        switch (a)
        {
        case 1:
            return "Aren";
        case 2:
            return "Cali";
        case 3:
            return "Nona";
        case 4:
            return "Lanest";
        case 5:
            return "Jos";
        case 6:
            return "Anion";
        case 7:
            return "Yanner";
        case 8:
            return "Lannen";
        case 9:
            return "Yeager";
        case 10:
            return "Valo";
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
        }
}
public static String city2()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = 1+r.nextInt(10);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        return "crest";
    case 2:
        return "ton";
    case 3:
        return "main";
    case 4:
        return " City";
    case 5:
        return "bain";
    case 6:
        return "quell";
    case 7:
        return "ia";
    case 8:
        return "kal";
    case 9:
        return "fale";
    case 10:
        return "en";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
public static String town()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = 1+r.nextInt(10);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        return "River";
    case 2:
        return "Forest";
    case 3:
        return "Uain";
    case 4:
        return "White";
    case 5:
        return "Dark";
    case 6:
        return "Snell";
    case 7:
        return "Fire";
    case 8:
        return "Cala";
    case 9:
        return "Hali";
    case 10:
        return "Galla";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
public static String town2()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = 1+r.nextInt(10);
    switch (a)
    {

    case 1:
        return " Town";
    case 2:
        return " Point";
    case 3:
        return " Pass";
    case 4:
        return "rock";
    case 5:
        return "len";
    case 6:
        return "den";
    case 7:
        return "gon";
    case 8:
        return "hos";
    case 9:
        return "fax";
    case 10:
        return "lest";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
public static String village()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = 1+r.nextInt(10);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        return "Fen";
    case 2:
        return "River";
    case 3:
        return "Cold";
    case 4:
        return "Rock";
    case 5:
        return "Agri";
    case 6:
        return "Wolf";
    case 7:
        return "Goro";
    case 8:
        return "Hung";
    case 9:
        return "Fale";
    case 10:
        return "Lest";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
public static String village2()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = 1+r.nextInt(10);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        return "ville";
    case 2:
        return " Village";
    case 3:
        return " Peak";
    case 4:
        return " Way";
    case 5:
        return "mill";
    case 6:
        return " Wood";
    case 7:
        return "gron";
    case 8:
        return " Cove";
    case 9:
        return " Forest";
    case 10:
        return "nar";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
public static String percent()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = 1+r.nextInt(10);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        return "of about 95%";
    case 2:
        return "of about 90%";
    case 3:
        return "of about 80%";
    case 4:
        return "of about 70%";
    case 5:
        return "of about 60%";
    case 6:
        return "of about 50%";
    case 7:
        return "of about 40%";
    case 8:
        return "of about 30%";
    case 9:
        return "of about 20%";
    case 10:
        return "of about 10%";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
public static String demo()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = 1+r.nextInt(23);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        return "Calishite Humans";
    case 2:
        return "Orks";
    case 3:
        return "High Elves";
    case 4:
        return "Dark Elves (Drow)";
    case 5:
        return "Stout Halflings";
    case 6:
        return "Rock Gnomes";
    case 7:
        return "Mountain Dwarfs";
    case 8:
        return "Hill Dwarfs";
    case 9:
        return "Wood Elves";
    case 10:
        return "Lightfoot Halflings";
    case 11:
        return "Dragonborn";
    case 12:
        return "Forrest Gnomes";
    case 13:
        return "Chondathan Humans";
    case 14:
        return "Damaran Humans";
    case 15:
        return "Illuskan Humans";
    case 16:
        return "Mulan Humans";
    case 17:
        return "Rashemi Humans";
    case 18:
        return "Shou Humans";
    case 19:
        return "Tethyrian Humans";
    case 20:
        return "Turami Humans";
    case 21:
        return "Half-Elves";
    case 22:
        return "Half-Orcs";
    case 23:
        return "Tieflings";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
public static String demo2()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = 1+r.nextInt(23);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        return "Calishite Humans";
    case 2:
        return "Orks";
    case 3:
        return "High Elves";
    case 4:
        return "Dark Elves (Drow)";
    case 5:
        return "Stout Halflings";
    case 6:
        return "Rock Gnomes";
    case 7:
        return "Mountain Dwarfs";
    case 8:
        return "Hill Dwarfs";
    case 9:
        return "Wood Elves";
    case 10:
        return "Lightfoot Halflings";
    case 11:
        return "Dragonborn";
    case 12:
        return "Forrest Gnomes";
    case 13:
        return "Chondathan Humans";
    case 14:
        return "Damaran Humans";
    case 15:
        return "Illuskan Humans";
    case 16:
        return "Mulan Humans";
    case 17:
        return "Rashemi Humans";
    case 18:
        return "Shou Humans";
    case 19:
        return "Tethyrian Humans";
    case 20:
        return "Turami Humans";
    case 21:
        return "Half-Elves";
    case 22:
        return "Half-Orcs";
    case 23:
        return "Tieflings";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
public static String status()

{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = 1+r.nextInt(10);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        return " joyus and filled with spirit.";
    case 2:
        return " in a state of unrest.";
    case 3:
        return " hostile towards strangers.";
    case 4:
        return " open to newcommers and glad";
    case 5:
        return " varied. Depending on who you ask.";
    case 6:
        return " Strange and unsetting.";
    case 7:
        return " disgusting and obnoxious.";
    case 8:
        return " afraid of strange people, fear is in them.";
    case 9:
        return " happy and full of cultured indeviduals who love sharing their works of art.";
    case 10:
        return " proud, they love their home.";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
public static String geo()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = 1+r.nextInt(10);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        return " lined with hills,";
    case 2:
        return " lined with mountains,";
    case 3:
        return " surrounded by flatlands,";
    case 4:
        return " bordered by a desert,";
    case 5:
        return " on the coast, with a rocky shore,";
    case 6:
        return " on the coast, with a sandy shore,";
    case 7:
        return " filled with cracks in the ground, seemingly bottomless,";
    case 8:
        return " built into the mountains,";
    case 9:
        return " cold, bitter, and dry, filled with evergreen forrests,";
    case 10:
        return " alongside a jungle, with massive canopy trees,";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
public static String geo2()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = 1+r.nextInt(10);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        return " and large trees, and has a nearby lake.";
    case 2:
        return " with little to no vegitation, imports are what this town lives on.";
    case 3:
        return " and is full of fertile land, the farmers here are prosperous.";
    case 4:
        return " under the protection of large mountains and rought terrain; lining the horizon.";
    case 5:
        return " and the visible ocean water laps on the shore gentaly.";
    case 6:
        return " the visible ocean water is rough, and would be hard to navigate.";
    case 7:
        return " and strange jagged rocks protrude randomly along the landscape.";
    case 8:
        return " and purple glows eminate from a very large mountain peak in the far distance.";
    case 9:
        return " and colourful skys cause the buildings to shine with a great elegance.";
    case 10:
        return " built partially underground.";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
}
```

Sorry for the long block of code, the methods that return a string are, for the most part, the same.

Comment: Ayyy, here's an upvote for you.

Comment: Congratulations, your question made it to this week's CR newsletter!

Comment: @Mat'sMug What does that mean? :o

Comment: Extra votes (well *views* at least) for everyone! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two major concepts your code ***needs***.

1. Arrays
2. Objects

## Arrays

```
public static String status()

{
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = 1+r.nextInt(10);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        return " joyus and filled with spirit.";
    case 2:
        return " in a state of unrest.";
    case 3:
        return " hostile towards strangers.";
    case 4:
        return " open to newcommers and glad";
    case 5:
        return " varied. Depending on who you ask.";
    case 6:
        return " Strange and unsetting.";
    case 7:
        return " disgusting and obnoxious.";
    case 8:
        return " afraid of strange people, fear is in them.";
    case 9:
        return " happy and full of cultured indeviduals who love sharing their works of art.";
    case 10:
        return " proud, they love their home.";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
```

This code can be easily rewritten if the Strings are stored in an array:

```
public static String status() {
    String[] values = { " joyus and filled with spirit.", 
        " in a state of unrest.",
        " hostile towards strangers.",
        " open to newcommers and glad",
        " varied. Depending on who you ask.",
        " Strange and unsetting.",
        " disgusting and obnoxious.",
        " afraid of strange people, fear is in them.",
        " happy and full of cultured indeviduals who love sharing their works of art.",
        " proud, they love their home.",
    };
    Random r = new Random();
    return values[r.nextInt(values.length)];
}
```

Each and every one of your methods that return a random string can be rewritten like that.

Although you should know that it is better to *re-use* the `Random` object. You should not create a new one each and every time as that reduces the "randomness".

You can make the `Random` like this once in your class:

```
public static final Random random = new Random();
```

Then all methods can access it, without creating their own.

---

## Objects

Your towns and villages and cities are essentially the same. I don't want to give you too much information right now, but I would write a `class` to represent a Town/Village/City.

I would strongly recommend reading this tutorial on the subject: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

You could make one class for a `Town`, one for `Village` and one for `City`, although essentially as it's the same thing in the core you could make just one class for it all.

You seem to know how to make methods but you need to learn how to make ***non-static methods***. When a method is non-static it belongs to an object instead of in a "global" space.

---

Once you have improved your code a bit, I would recommend coming back here and [post a new, follow-up, question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Huh, thank you very much! I'm glad I found this site, it's really been improving my coding.

Comment: I can definitely relate. Welcome!

Comment: @BuySomeChips It would be wise to incorporate [feedback from previous answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/77295/9357) when asking questions. Simon is basically giving the same advice I gave for `getRandomWord()` in your Hangman game.

Answer (score 10):

To add to the Simon's answer: You did not wrote a *generator*! You wrote just a piece of code *printing* how a city/town *could look like*, but there's no such thing like city in your code. As he already wrote, you need objects. To elaborate on it:

- a program generating and printing some values is unusable for anything else
- create an object representing what you work with
- fill it with data
- add a method `toString()`

This way for printing the data, all you need is `System.out.println(city)`. As a bonus, you can see the string representation in the debugger.

In general, it's the [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). The class represents the city, one method fills it, another one converts it to a string, etc.

---

> Although you should know that it is better to re-use the Random object.

One big advantage of this is the possibility to seed it with a constant and thus making it reproducible. This is invaluable in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Another beginner mistake is putting content in your code. All those switch/case statements are horrible;

- your code is much larger than it needs to be
- any changes to content requires recompiling

The content needs to be a resource and the code needs to read it.

```
public class FileResourceReader {

    private File file;
    private List<String> values;
    private Random random;

    public FileResourceReader(File file) {
        this.file = file;
        this.values = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    /**
     * Reads the resource. This must be called before getRandomLine()
     * is called.
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public void readResource() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            values.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    /**
     * Gets a random line from the resource.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getRandomLine() {
        int position = random.nextInt(values.size());
        return values.get(position);
    }
}
```

Then you can initialise a reader like this;

```
FileResourceReader cities = new FileResourceReader(new File("d:\\tmp\\cities.txt"));
cities.readResource();
```

and every time you want to get a random line from it;

```
cities.getRandomLine()
```

Comment: Because Random is thread safe and pretty efficient, you could make the Random static instead of them each initializing their own.